# Run RMarkdown (.rmd) from inside another .rmd without creating HTML output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am making my code more modular and would like to run multiple RMarkdown files from one overall RMarkdown. I believe I could do this if I translated all my RMarkdown files to .R scripts and  used `source()`, but I like the document-like nature of RMarkdown and I can describe what I'm doing as I'm doing it in plain text.

The goal is to wrangle data and export a usable `.sav` file. I want to run `clean.rmd` from `run.rmd`, but I don't want any HTML/pdf/etc. output. Removing the output line in the YAML header doesn't prevent output. If there is a way to do this without translating everything to .R scripts, I would be very appreciative. Thank you.

#### clean.rmd: Script that does the cleaning

````
---
title: "clean"
author: "jrcalabrese"
date: "12/30/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
```

```{r}
data(cars)
cars <- cars %>%
  mutate(newvar = speed + dist)
```

```{r}
write_spss(cars, "~/Documents/cars_new.sav", compress = FALSE)
```
````

#### run.rmd: Script that runs clean.rmd

````
---
title: "run"
author: "jrcalabrese"
date: "12/30/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
rmarkdown::render("~/Documents/clean.rmd")
```
````

Comment: It seems odd that your code blocks are not within `\`\`\`{r}` fences, is that because of the SO interface and code formatting? If so, then ... insert the actual rmarkdown including code-fences, then highlight the code and press `Ctrl-K` which will indent the code, showing the code fences as expected. It'll present a better-formatted question, as we'll have a real working example. Thanks! (If need be, I can edit the question and demonstrate my point, but I don't want to change your question if your real docs don't have the fences.)

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/prevent-rmarkdown-document-from-creating-any-output-file/81871/4) helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your help! This function works:

````
---
title: "run"
author: "jrcalabrese"
date: "12/30/2021"
#output: html_document
---

```{r}
source_rmd = function(file, ...) {
  tmp_file = tempfile(fileext=".R")
  on.exit(unlink(tmp_file), add = TRUE)
  knitr::purl(file, output=tmp_file)
  source(file = tmp_file, ...)
}
```

```{r}
source_rmd("~/Documents/clean.rmd")
```
````